# Making a name an English name

Tags: names, transliteration

How does one go about taking a name (or word) from another language and making it an English name? I know of examples such as Yeshua being turned to Joshua or Yonatan turning into Jonathan, but I do not know the rule itself.

Edit: To help specify my question:  I am trying to change is the Malayalam word for "Heart" (Hrdayarn) I want to use it as a name but it sounds just a little off.

Comment: The rule for Biblical names (like Yeshua and Yonatan) is to figure out which personage in the Bible you are named after, and then figure out what their name is in English Bibles.

Comment: There is no verbal rule. Each instance is treated separately.

Comment: The question you ask is rather like asking how one common language, Latin, came to be reshaped into Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, French, Romanian, ...  The issue has less to do with how words are written than with how they sound.  In particular it is a matter of how a population with one phonetic range hears and pronounced a name from a population with a quite different phonetic range.

Comment: Well the specific word I am trying to change is the Malayalam word for "Heart" (Hrdayarn) 

I want to use it as a name but it sounds just a little off.

Comment: For that example, English speakers are going to want to insert a vowel of some kind  between the *h* and the *r*. Figuring out which vowel will give the least objectionable result and adding it in will help us pronounce it closer to what you expect (but of course still quite differently from a fluent Malayalam speaker).

Comment: "How does one go about ...?" One doesn't. There exist equivalent English names.

Comment: @ThePhoton: That is a good point about inserting a vowel. It sounds most like "Hur-day-arn" or "Hir-day-arn"

Comment: Who would use the name: a child or adult, a male or female? Also is the person an Indian and living in India?

Comment: I am an Indian living in America. My children are half indian and I am trying to find good names for future children.

Comment: Choosing a new name, whether created out of whole cloth, inspired by foreign languages, or just chosen from a name list, is very much an art. There's a lot of opinion involved, depending on how you want it to sound in the new language.

Comment: Can you attach a sound file to your post to make clear how the name soundsin Malayalam

Answer (score 3):

A foreign word starting *hr-* with a vowel immediately following would be pronounced **either** by omitting the *h* entirely **or** by pronouncing that digraph *χr-.* But there is no easy way in English to pronounce three intial consonants like *hrd-;* we would probably have to insert a vowel sound, *her*.

The foreign word *hrdayarn* would be most likely to be pronounced /ˈhɜːdɑˌjɑːn/ or /ˈhɜːʳdɑˌjɑːʳn/, with the stress on the first syllable and the *y* as part of the last syllable (because that forms the recognisable word *yarn*). If that's an acceptable approximation, great! If not, and I guess that the consonant cluster *hrd-* should not in fact be stressed, then you will either need to choose a name which can be pronounced at least reasonably well by English speakers, or ensure that you introduce yourself so that your name can be heard and copied. While *hr-* will still need to be *her-*, /hɜː'dɑɪjən/ is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a traditional English name for the first name, and the Malayalam name as a middle name?

For example, **Cora** means “little heart” in Latin, but it comes originally from the Greek goddess [Persephone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cora), which makes it a very strong name.

There are other choices, depending on what *heart* means to you. For example, there’s a site called [mom365.com](https://www.mom365.com/baby-names/baby-name-search?m=1&Gender=U&Meaning=brave&pageNumber=2) where you can search for names “by meaning”.

It’s difficult to know how children will react to the name they are given. However, if a name from an outside language is not easily pronounced by the child’s teachers and peers, it will be ruthlessly converted into something that can. So you may end up with an “English name” that’s not quite what you were hoping for.

Comment: I have thought about using other words for Heart, but I want it to sound like "Hrdayarn"

Comment: @InshalChenet The closest names that I can think of among people that I know personally are *Darla* for a girl or *Dylan* for a boy. Wishing you luck, anyway.